# nodejs - fs.createReadStream().pipe, how to know size of file issue

Tags: file, http, node.js, httpresponse

I am writing my own HTTP module, if I need to response with a binary file, e.g. .jpg,

I load the file using: `body = fs.createReadStream(pathOfFile)`.

When I generate the response I use:`body.pipe(socket);`

But as its HTTP response, I had like to add a `Content-Length` header.

I couldn't find an easy way to do it, fs.stat doesn't give the result immediately but just after I called pipe.

Anyway to know what to send in  `Content-Length` header. ?

Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to tell whether you're asking about length of files, or width and height of images `\-:`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well you should only send the response and pipe the file after you get the size with fs.stat, like so:

```
fs.stat(file_path, function(error, stat) {
  if (error) { throw error; }
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type' : 'image/gif',
    'Content-Length' : stat.size
  });
  // do your piping here
});
```

Comment: This introduces a race condition - the file might change between the stat and the piping

Answer (score 3):

There is also a synchronous version (since you'll be blocking on file I/O anyway...) as mentioned in this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686)

```
var stat = fs.statSync(pathOfFile);
response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type' : 'image/jpeg',
    'Content-Length' : stat.size
});
// pipe contents
```

Comment: You definitely don't want to do this when writing a web server or any other multi-request system... the whole point of `fs.stat()` is that it's NON-BLOCKING. If you are writing a web server and you use `stat` instead of `statSync` then your single threaded nodejs process can continue serving _other requests_ while the file I/O happens...

Comment: Not a solution for web server. Anybody absolutely want to not block thread for NodeJs engine