# How to check if a file (given by full path) exists? node js

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I thought I could do it with the 'fs' module, but i couldnt find the right function.

Comment: I believe this question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js

Comment: thanks. I dont know how i missed it..

Answer (score 2):

```
fs = require('fs');        
fs.exists(path, function( exists ) {        
    console.log( ( exists  ? "File is there" : "File is not there" ) );         
});
```

Comment: fs = require('fs');        
    console.log( fs.statSync(path).isFile() ); // True or False

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation for the `fs` module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html), in particular the "`stat`" family of functions (stat, fstat, lstat, statSync, fstatSync, lstatSync).