# How to determine is string represent a directory or a file in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check synchronously if file/directory exists in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js)

For example, i have a string "C:/dev/image.folder", and i want to determine, is it directory or a file (synchronously). How can i do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can click on the big checkmarks next to answers to your questions to acknowledge that they've solved your problem.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I found an answer - described in
[this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Query the entry
stats = fs.lstatSync('/the/path');

// Is it a directory?
if (stats.isDirectory()) {
    // Yes it is
}
```

See T.J. Crowder's answer here: [Check synchronously if file/directory exists in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js)

Comment: You could *at least* have mentioned the [source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4482701) of your answer.

Comment: @RobW Is that normal protocol? I'm new to this.

Comment: It shows respect to the original author, and others can see the full version (with additional details). In this case, you should actually have voted to close the question as a duplicate, because it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: I don't think I'm able to vote to close. Also, is there a way to get links to specific answers?

Comment: You can click the "link" button below each answer to link to that specific one.  Also, it takes 3,000 rep to vote to close.  Before you get to 3,000, you can use the "flag" link underneath questions to flag it as a duplicate (choose "doesn't belong here" and then "exact duplicate").