# Create Directory When Writing To File In Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been tinkering with Node.js and found a little problem.  I've got a script which resides in a directory called `data`.  I want the script to write some data to a file in a subdirectory within the `data` subdirectory.  However I am getting the following error:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, open 'D:\data\tmp\test.txt'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'D:\\data\\tmp\\test.txt' }
```

The code is as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("tmp/test.txt", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }
});
```

Can anybody help me in finding out how to make Node.js create the directory structure if it does not exits for writing to a file?

Comment: `fs.promises.mkdir(path.dirname("tmp/test.txt"), {recursive: true}).then(x => fs.promises.writeFile("tmp/test.txt", "Hey there!"))`

Answer (score 313, accepted):

### Node > 10.12.0

[fs.mkdir](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_options_callback) now accepts a `{ recursive: true }` option like so:

```
// Creates /tmp/a/apple, regardless of whether `/tmp` and /tmp/a exist.
fs.mkdir('/tmp/a/apple', { recursive: true }, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

or with a promise:

```
fs.promises.mkdir('/tmp/a/apple', { recursive: true }).catch(console.error);
```

Notes,

1. In many case you would use `fs.mkdirSync` rather than `fs.mkdir`
2. It is harmless / has no effect to include a trailing slash.
3. mkdirSync/mkdir no nothing harmlessly if the directory already exists, there's no need to check for existence.

### Node <= 10.11.0

You can solve this with a package like [mkdirp](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp) or [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra). If you don't want to install a package, please see Tiago Peres França's answer below.

Comment: That's the one I'm going with...those stats won me over.

Comment: note that `fs.promises` is still experimental https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api

Comment: If you use this because you're trying to create a local directory temp file, you must pass in './tmp/a/apple'

Comment: @rom , "cars/ford/mustang" will also appear in the current local directory.

Answer (score 189):

If you don't want to use any additional package, you can call the following function before creating your file:

```
var path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs');

function ensureDirectoryExistence(filePath) {
  var dirname = path.dirname(filePath);
  if (fs.existsSync(dirname)) {
    return true;
  }
  ensureDirectoryExistence(dirname);
  fs.mkdirSync(dirname);
}
```

Comment: This should use `statSync` instead of `existsSync`, based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js/4482701#4482701

Comment: @GavinR You're right, fs.existsSync is deprecated. I'll update the answer.

Comment: `path` is also a package that needs to be required just as `fs`:  `var path = require('path')` in case anyone is wondering. See [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html).

Comment: [`fs.existsSync` is *not* deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path), only `fs.exists` is.

Comment: @RafaelCichocki I just edited the answer to reflect your comment. Thank You for the observation.

Comment: There's been some confusion about whether the function fs.existsSync has been deprecated or not. At first, by my understanding, I thought it was, so I updated the answer to reflect this. But now, as pointed by @zzzzBov, the documentation clearly states that only fs.exists has been deprecated, the use of fs.existsSync is still valid. For this reason I deleted the previous code and my answer now contains only the simpler solution (with the use of fs.existsSync).

Comment: Why is the recusive call to ensureDirectoryExistence() called before the fs.mkdirSync?

Comment: @chrismarx imagine the following path: "/home/documents/a/b/c/myfile.txt". "/home/documents" exists, while everything in front of it doesn't. When "ensureDirectoryExistence" is called for the 1st time, dirname is "/home/documents/a/b/c". I can't call fs.mkdirSync(dirname) right now because "/home/documents/a/b" also doesn't exist. To create the directory "c", I need to first ensure the existence of "/home/documents/a/b".

Comment: Oh, duh, yes, thank you, I knew it had to create the missing directories, wasn't seeing how the recursion worked here, thanks!

Comment: This almost works but does not completely work! If the argument is just a directory structure without any filename, it fails. For example, it failed for me when I passed in an argument like this: "./Test/"

Comment: @Suhas It does work, since the question explicitly asks how to create a directory while writing a FILE. ./Test/ is not a file path. However, it is extremely simple to adapt this answer to solve your specific problem. just pass a dummy path (./Test/dummy) or edit the function itself to expect a directory.

Comment: @Offenso what does Jesus have to do with any of this?

Comment: Why the "ensureDirectoryExistence(dirname);" has camed before the "fs.mkdirSync(dirname);"
It's something like wole loop.

Comment: You can also just do `fs.mkdirSync(path.dirname(filePath), { recursive: true });` . If the directory doesnt exist it will be created

Answer (score 83):

With [node-fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) you can do it easily.

### Install it

```
npm install --save fs-extra
```

Then use the `outputFile` method. Its documentation says:

> Almost the same as `writeFile` (i.e. it overwrites), except that if the
> parent directory does not exist, it's created.

You can use it in four ways.

#### Async/await

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');

await fse.outputFile('tmp/test.txt', 'Hey there!');
```

#### Using Promises

If you use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), this is the code:

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');

fse.outputFile('tmp/test.txt', 'Hey there!')
   .then(() => {
       console.log('The file has been saved!');
   })
   .catch(err => {
       console.error(err)
   });
```

#### Callback style

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');

fse.outputFile('tmp/test.txt', 'Hey there!', err => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('The file has been saved!');
  }
})
```

#### Sync version

If you want a sync version, just use this code:

```
const fse = require('fs-extra')

fse.outputFileSync('tmp/test.txt', 'Hey there!')
```

For a complete reference, check the [`outputFile` documentation](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/outputFile.md) and all [node-fs-extra supported methods](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#methods).

Answer (score 28):

Shameless plug alert!

You will have to check for each directory in the path structure you want and create it manually if it doesn't exist. All the tools to do so are already there in Node's fs module, but you can do all of that simply with my mkpath module: https://github.com/jrajav/mkpath

Comment: will that create the file directly or just the directory structure?  I'm looking for a solution which create the file along with the directory structure when creating the file.

Comment: Just the directory structure. You would the mkdir/path first and, if there weren't any errors, proceed to writing your file. It would be simple enough to write a function to do both simultaneously, given a full path to a file to write - just split off the filename using [path.basename](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_p_ext)

Comment: In fact, it was so simple that I [wrote it in 2 minutes](https://gist.github.com/4140206). :) (Untested)

Comment: Update: Tested and edited, please try it again if it didn't work the first time.

Comment: @Kiyura How is this different from the widely used [mkdirp](https://npmjs.org/package/mkdirp)?

Comment: Dammit! I gave into your `shameless` advertisement! Thanks for the help!

Comment: anyone who is interested. the module is available on npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkpath

Comment: Jesus.. Use recursive: `fs.promises.mkdir(path.dirname(file), {recursive: true}).then(x => fs.promises.writeFile(file, data))`

Answer (score 18):

Same answer as above, but with `async await` and ready to use!

```js
const fs = require('fs/promises');
const path = require('path');

async function isExists(path) {
  try {
    await fs.access(path);
    return true;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
};

async function writeFile(filePath, data) {
  try {
    const dirname = path.dirname(filePath);
    const exist = await isExists(dirname);
    if (!exist) {
      await fs.mkdir(dirname, {recursive: true});
    }
    
    await fs.writeFile(filePath, data, 'utf8');
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}
```

Example:

```js
(async () {
  const data = 'Hello, World!';
  await writeFile('dist/posts/hello-world.html', data);
})();
```

Comment: Amazing answer.

Answer (score 11):

Since I cannot comment yet, I'm posting an enhanced answer based on @tiago-peres-frança fantastic solution (thanks!). His code does not make directory in a case where only the last directory is missing in the path, e.g. the input is "C:/test/abc" and "C:/test" already exists. Here is a snippet that works:

```
function mkdirp(filepath) {
    var dirname = path.dirname(filepath);

    if (!fs.existsSync(dirname)) {
        mkdirp(dirname);
    }

    fs.mkdirSync(filepath);
}
```

Comment: That's because @tiago's solution expects a **file** path. In your case, `abc` is interpreted as the file you need to create a directory for. To also create the `abc` directory, add a dummy file to your path, e.g. `C:/test/abc/dummy.txt`.

Comment: Use recursive: `fs.promises.mkdir(path.dirname(file), {recursive: true}).then(x => fs.promises.writeFile(file, data))`

Comment: @Offenso it's the best solution, but for Node.js version 10.12 and above only.

Answer (score 10):

My advise is: **try not to rely on dependencies when you can easily do it with few lines of codes**

Here's what you're trying to achieve in **14** lines of code:

```
fs.isDir = function(dpath) {
    try {
        return fs.lstatSync(dpath).isDirectory();
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
};
fs.mkdirp = function(dirname) {
    dirname = path.normalize(dirname).split(path.sep);
    dirname.forEach((sdir,index)=>{
        var pathInQuestion = dirname.slice(0,index+1).join(path.sep);
        if((!fs.isDir(pathInQuestion)) && pathInQuestion) fs.mkdirSync(pathInQuestion);
    });
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't the third line be better like this? `return fs.lstatSync(dpath).isDirectory()`, otherwise what would happen if isDirectory() returns false?

Comment: Use recursive: `fs.promises.mkdir(path.dirname(file), {recursive: true}).then(x => fs.promises.writeFile(file, data))`

Comment: @Offenso it's not supported by a node 8

Answer (score 3):

As simple as this, create recursively if does not exist:

```js
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just published this module because I needed this functionality.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/filendir

It works like a wrapper around Node.js fs methods. So you can use it exactly the same way you would with `fs.writeFile` and `fs.writeFileSync` (both async and synchronous writes)

Answer (score 1):

IDK why, but this mkdir always make an extra directory with the file name if also the filename is included in the path; e.g.

```
// fileName = './tmp/username/some-random.jpg';
try {
  mkdirSync(fileName, { recursive: true })
} catch (error) {};
```

[image]

### Solution

It can be solved this way: `fileName.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')` which only make directories up to the last dir, not the filename itself.

```
// fileName = './tmp/username/some-random.jpg';
try {
  mkdirSync(fileName.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/'), { recursive: true })
} catch (error) {};
```

[image]

Comment: just use `const fileDir = path.dirname(fileName)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution to create the folder with all the needed subfolders, and then writing the file, all in one function.

This is an example assuming you are creating a backup file and you want to pass the backup folder name in the function (hence the name of the variables)

```
  createFile(backupFolderName, fileName, fileContent) {
    const csvFileName = `${fileName}.csv`;

    const completeFilePath = join(process.cwd(), 'backups', backupFolderName);

    fs.mkdirSync(completeFilePath, { recursive: true });

    fs.writeFileSync(join(completeFilePath, csvFileName), fileContent, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(csvFileName + ' file saved');
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it my answer won't cover all the use-cases, there is an elegant way for creating files in a newly created unique folder *inside os temp dir*:

```js
import { mkdtempSync } from 'fs';
import { tmpdir } from 'os';
import { join } from 'path';

const filePath = join(mkdtempSync(join(tmpdir(), 'workspace-')), 'file.txt')

// write file
```

This example takes advantage of the fact that `mkdtempSync` returns path to the newly created dir.