# Check if file exist in Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I need to check if a file exists in a gulp task, i know i can use some node functions from node, there are two:

`fs.exists()` and `fs.existsSync()`

The problem is that in the node documentation, is saying that these functions will be deprecated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check synchronously if file/directory exists in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use [`fs.access`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback)

```
fs.access('/etc/passwd', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        // file/path is not visible to the calling process
        console.log(err.message);
        console.log(err.code);
    }
});
```

List of available error codes [here](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_code)

---

> Using `fs.access()` to check for the accessibility of a file before calling `fs.open(), fs.readFile()` or `fs.writeFile()` is not recommended. Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change the file's state between the two calls. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file is not accessible.

Comment: The current node documentatión [does not recommend using stat to check wether a file exists][1]:

  [1]: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback

Answer (score 4):

You could add

```
var f;

try {
  var f = require('your-file');
} catch (error) {

  // ....
}

if (f) {
  console.log(f);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As of 2018, you can use [`fs.existsSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path):

> fs.exists() is deprecated, but fs.existsSync() is not. The callback parameter to fs.exists() accepts parameters that are inconsistent with other Node.js callbacks. fs.existsSync() does not use a callback.

[See this answer for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482701/4842857)

Answer (score 1):

I believe `fs-access` package has been depreciated alternatively you may want to use:

`path-exists`.

`file-exists`.

### Intracutions (path-exists):

```
npm install path-exists --save

const myFile = '/my_file_to_ceck.html';
const exists = pathExists.sync(myFile);
console.log(exists);
```

### Intracutions (file-exists):

```
npm install file-exists --save


const fileExists = require('file-exists');
const myFile = '/my_file_to_ceck.html';
fileExists(myFile, (err, exists) => console.log(exists))
```

[NPM Link: path exists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-exists)

[NPM Link: file exists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-exists)

Answer (score 0):

The node documentatión [does not recommend using stat to check wether a file exists](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback):

> Using fs.stat() to check for the existence of a file before calling fs.open(), fs.readFile() or fs.writeFile() is not recommended.
>   Instead, **user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle
>   the error raised** if the file is not available.
>
> **To check if a file exists without manipulating it afterwards,
>   fs.access() is recommended.**

If you don't need to read or write the file you should use `fs.access`, the simple and asynchronous way is:

```js
try {
 fs.accessSync(path)
 // the file exists
}catch(e){
 // the file doesn't exists
}
```