# Setting default environment variables in Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, environment-variables

I'm working on an app that connects to third-party APIs which require the use of an APP ID and SECRET KEY.

I am storing these values as environment variables in heroku, so that  I don't need to expose them in my code.

If I deploy to heroku, it will use heroku's environment variables to resolve these API credentials.

If I'm working on it locally, I want to use my `config.js` module, and lookup the API credentials there.  NOTE: This `config.js` file is included in my `.gitignore` so that these credentials never end up in the cloud.

The problematic code is this:

```
var api_secret = process.env.API_SECRET || require('../../config.js').secret;
```

When I run this locally, I've got no issues. Meaning, it is unable to resolve the environment variable, so instead it uses the `secret` from within `config.js`.

When I run it on heroku, it DOES throw an error telling me that `module 'config.js' could not be found`.  This makes sense, because it was never pushed up with the rest of the repo, by virtue that it is in my `.gitignore`.

Because heroku is parsing through my code before it ever runs, the `require('../../config.js')` is problematic. It is trying to lookup a file that doesn't exist.

How can I solve the issue of using environment variables when deployed, and the `config.js` module when running locally?

Answer (score 1):

On the Heroku dashboard for your application, you can set config variables. If you have the Heroku Toolbelt set up on your machine, you can also use:

```
heroku config:set API_SECRET=secret
```

See [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) for more.

Edit: Think I may have misunderstood the question. I would suggest, if possible, using the [dotenv npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to set your config variables locally.

If not, another thing to check would be that the `config.js` package is in your `package.json` file, because Heroku will use this to build your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to push your `config.js` to heroky at all, you can just follow the following to determine whether the config file exists or not with a try catch and the file system module:

[Check synchronously if file/directory exists in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js)

In your case:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    api_secret,
    config;

try {
    // Check whether config.js exists
    config = fs.lstatSync('../../config.js');
    // If we reach this line then config.js exists, yay!
    api_secret = process.env.API_SECRET || require('../../config.js').secret;
    // or alternatively  api_secret = require('../../config.js').secret; 
    // depending on your logic

}
catch (e) {
    // else config.js does not exist
    api_secret = process.env.API_SECRET
}
```

To run Heroku commands programmatically, you can set up a free Ruby app and make it do what you want through API calls. Use Heroku-api. See https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb

If you want to set Heroku commands manually, you can set env variables on Heroku either with the command `heroku config:set MYVAR=MYVALUE` or through the Heroku dashboard (Click on your app > settings > reveal config vars > edit).