# fs.statSync throws error if file does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am attempting to determine if a file exists. If it does not exist, I would like my code to continue so it will be created. When I use the following code, if the file exists, it prints that 'it exists'. If it does not exist, it crashes my app. Here is my code:

```
var checkDuplicateFile = function(){
    var number = room.number.toString();
    var stats = fs.statSync(number);
    if(stat){
        console.log('it exists');
    }else{
        console.log('it does not exist');
    }

};
```

Comment: check this question, answer it is similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js

Comment: That doesn't help me. It does not answer the question I asked.

Comment: can't you use the async version of the function?  https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your application is crashing because you're not wrapping your `fs.statSync` in a `try/catch` block. Sync functions in node don't return the error like they would in their `async` versions. Instead, they throw their errors which need to be caught.

```
try {
  var stats = fs.statSync(number);
  console.log('it exists');
}
catch(err) {
    console.log('it does not exist');
}
```

If your app doesn't require this operation to be synchronous (block further execution until this operation is finished) then I would use the async version.

```
fs.stat(number, function(err, data) {
  if (err) 
    console.log('it does not exist');
  else 
    console.log('it exists');
});
```