# Create file if it does not exist, then write logs to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Trying to set up an environment that:

`server.js`:
When the server is created, it will check if the a series of files exist: [api.log, error.log, access.log], if they do not yet exist, it will create them.

`routes/api.js`: 
I can use the file created at start up to, on api errors, log the error.

A lot of the advice revolves around [fs.exists()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) which is now deprecated.

I am struggling to piece together the order of events, shall `server.js` check for files, act accordingly, then open a stream? Or must `routes/api.js` open the stream and write to it on every error?

I am using Node v5.0.0

Comment: What about `fs.statSync`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4482701/4989460

Comment: @stdob-- that is what I will be using for the check, any ideas about how I then use it? Is it as simple as referencing the file in a createWriteStream?  Now that I can ensure the file will have been created?

Comment: Okay, I understand. Given the fact that the log files can write from different functions and at the same time, it will be better once to create an object of type "logger" - for example, `winston` [ https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#multiple-transports-of-the-same-type ].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should never check for the existence of a file and then do something depending on whether the file does or doesn't exist.  This is an anti-pattern: some other process might create or delete the file between when you check for the file's existence and when you then perform your next operation.  (Even the *`Sync` methods—which are themselves anti-patterns—are vulnerable to this problem.)

Instead, you should just do whatever it is you need to do and handle errors appropriately.

In this case, you can let `createWriteStream` do the work for you by specifying [`flags`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback).  You probably want either:

> - `'w'` - Open file for writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or truncated (if it exists).
> - `'a'` - Open file for appending. The file is created if it does not exist.

---

Realistically, you should be using [a logging library](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/compare-node-js-logging-winston-bunyan/).

Comment: It is now quite clear Winston is the appropriate way forward here, thank you.