# How to check if directory exists before writing to it (nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was going to use `fs.access` to see if a directory exists, then if it exists then write a file into that directory, if it's not then first create the directory and then write a file into it.

But in the docs it says this is not recommended `Using fs.access() to check for the accessibility of a file before calling fs.open(), fs.readFile() or fs.writeFile() is not recommended. Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change the file's state between the two calls.

Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file is not accessible.`

Is there a recommended way to check first then write ?

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js

Comment: is there an async way to do it though? @IshanJain

Comment: @georgej fs.exists was depreciated, But as node docs say, You can use `fs.stat()`, `fs.access()` or as other people have said, You can simply open the directory and make sure `err.code != ENOENT`

Answer (score 3):

As the doc you just quoted says, the recommended approach is to simply use `fs.open()`, `fs.readFile()` or `fs.writeFile()` to attempt to load the file, and handle the error if it throws one.

Comment: if it ends up throwing the error, would it be wise to go right into making the directory then writing a file to it or is that bad practice?  Should I show the user the error instead? @troyalford

Comment: I don't know your use case in order to determine that for you, unfortunately. In general, my advice would be: If your user is responsible for creating the file your program will read, prompt the user when you get the error. If your program is responsible for it - don't prompt the user, just create it.

Comment: gotcha, appreciate it