# Best approach to check folder/file exist before read and write to the file

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise

How can I check if the folder/file exist before read and write to the file? I did some search and it shows that using "fs.stat() or fs.access() to check if a folder/file exists" but I also read some related questions ([related question one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259928/why-is-using-fstat-not-recommended), [related question two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819917/how-to-check-if-directory-exists-before-writing-to-it-nodejs)) and it appears to be that I might get some kind of "race condition".

**I am thinking of doing below approach to avoid "race condition", am I still going to get some kind of "race condition" with below approach?:**

```
const checkIfFolderOrFileExist = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.access(filePath, constants.F_OK, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve("exist");
      }
    });
  });
};

const createFolder = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.mkdir(folderPath, { recursive: false }, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve("done");
      }
    });
  });
};

const writeToTheFile = (data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(filePath, data, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve("Done");
      }
    });
  });
};

const callBothPromiseFunction = async () => {
  /* Does below code has a possibility that I might get some kind of "race condition"? (I am using fs.access and fs.writeFile) */
  const folderOrFileExist = await checkIfFolderOrFileExist(); //<---- using fs.access
  if (folderOrFileExist === "exist") {
    const response = await writeToTheFile(someRandomData);
    /* some other js codes */
  } else {
    await createFolder();
    const response = await writeToTheFile(someRandomData);
    /* some other js codes */
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a really easy way to test that in javascript using the fs library

```
const fs = require('fs');

const filePath = '/path/to/file.txt';

fs.access(filePath, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(`${filePath} does not exist`);
  } else {
    // file exists, you can read or write to it here
  }
});
```

You just have to add your reading / writing code in the "else"

Answer (score 0):

I personally never had issues with accessing a file/folder before reading/writing to it, but if you want to be sure to prevent this, you can leverage two mechanisms.

**Failing promise**

Instead of first checking if the folder exists, just create the folder and ignore the error when the folder already exists.

```js
const ensureFolderExists = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.mkdir(folderPath, { recursive: false }, (err) => {
      resolve('done');
    });
  });
};

const callBothPromiseFunction = async () => {
  await ensureFolderExists();
  await writeToTheFile(someRandomData);
};
```

The only downside is that you can't detect any other errors. For example, when you don't have the permissions to create the folder.

**Recursive: true**

The second option is to set the `recursive` flag to `true`. This will automatically "swallow" errors generated by already existing folders.