# nodejs: Unable to read file contents

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to read the contents of a file. The file existence check passes, even then the file read excepts as shown below:

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.exists('c:\\abc.txt',function(exists){
    console.log("exists");
    fs.readFile('c:\\abc.txt', 'UTF-8', function (err,data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("err"+err);
            }            
            console.log("data:"+data);                
    });
});
```

Output

```
exists
errError: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\abc.txt'
data:undefined
```

How may I correct this.

Comment: fs.exists is deprecated for years, see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback

Comment: The backslash character cancels any "special meaning" the subsequent character has, so "\\" is read as simply "\", you would need to write "\\\\" in order to get "\\".  That is why is says no file "c:\abc.txt" with only one backslash even though you typed two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't checking that the result from `fs.exists` is that the file exists. You're just going ahead with your file read in the callback. You need to check the first argument to see if it's true (the file exists) or false (it doesn't). Currently, your code isn't using the `exists` parameter at all. (It also should exit the `readFile` callback or otherwise skip the bit using `data` if `err` isn't `null`.)

But [`fs.exists`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) has been deprecated for ages, and separately, there's no point in checking whether a file exists before trying to read it, since it can be created or deleted *after* the exists check but *before* the read. Just try to read the file, and handle the error if you can't:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('c:\\abc.txt', 'UTF-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("err"+err);
        return;
    }
    console.log("data:"+data);                
});
```

If you really want to check existence before reading, you could use [`fs.existsSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) (which is not deprecated), which at least reduces the window between the check for existence and reading the file, but it really still doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks @TJ Crowder, although ".exists" works for now but its mentioned that its no longer supported by community and might be deprecated in higher versions.

Comment: @StillNestling: *"...might be deprecated in higher versions"* It's deprecated **now**, and has been for years. At some point it may well be removed. I've been following this saga [a while now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js/4482701#4482701). I wouldn't suggest using deprecated APIs, particularly long-deprecated ones.