# Ionic checkFile(path,filename) NOT_FOUND_ERR

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

File Path - `file:///data/data/io.ionic.starter/data.json`

I wish to check if '**data.json**' exists in the mentioned path.

But I recieve an error - `{"code":1,"message":"NOT_FOUND_ERR"}`
Currently the file isn't present in the path so I am expecting the **Promise<>** to return **false**, but it ends up throwing an error.

Sample code:

```
var fileName = "data.json";
     this.file.checkFile(this.file.applicationStorageDirectory, fileName)
    .then((result) => {
    console.log('file exists :' + result);
    },(error){
    console.log('error : ' + JSON.stringify(error)});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js/35016418#35016418 https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats

Comment: Is this resolved ?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with **checkDir**.

At the end I found the problem. It works a little bit different than expected.

When the directory (or file in your case) exists, then indeed executes the **then** part. When the directory does not exists then it does not return a false value but instead goes to the error part (catch) with the code 1. 
So if the error code is 1 it means the file does not exists in the directory.

Answer (score 3):

Confirm your `dir` parameter passed to `checkFile`. It should end with '/'.