# How to manage log in session through headless chrome?

Tags: javascript, cookies, web-scraping, headless, puppeteer

I want to create a scraper that:

1. opens a headless browser,
2. goes to a [url](https://cs.money/),
3. logs in (there is steam oauth),
4. fills some inputs,
5. and clicks 2 buttons.

My problem is that every new instance of headless browser clears my login session, and then I need to login again and again...

**How to save it through instances?** (using puppeteer with headless chrome)

Or **how can I open already logged in chrome headless instance?** (if I have already logged in in my main chrome window)

Comment: See also [Puppeteer: how to store a session (including cookies, page state, local storage, etc) and continue later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987585/puppeteer-how-to-store-a-session-including-cookies-page-state-local-storage#57995750)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In puppeter you have access to the session cookies through `page.cookies()`.

So once you log in, you could get every cookie and save it in a json file:

```
const fs = require(fs);
const cookiesFilePath = 'cookies.json';
// Save Session Cookies
const cookiesObject = await page.cookies()
// Write cookies to temp file to be used in other profile pages
fs.writeFile(cookiesFilePath, JSON.stringify(cookiesObject),
 function(err) { 
  if (err) {
  console.log('The file could not be written.', err)
  }
  console.log('Session has been successfully saved')
})
```

Then, on your next iteration right before using `page.goto()` you can call `page.setCookie()` to load the cookies from the file one by one:

```
const previousSession = fs.existsSync(cookiesFilePath)
if (previousSession) {
  // If file exist load the cookies
  const cookiesString = fs.readFileSync(cookiesFilePath);
  const parsedCookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString);
  if (parsedCookies.length !== 0) {
    for (let cookie of parsedCookies) {
      await page.setCookie(cookie)
    }
    console.log('Session has been loaded in the browser')
  }
}
```

Checkout the docs:

- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagecookiesurls
- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetcookiecookies

Comment: jsonfile does not seem to work when headless: false, the documentation says "Note: this module cannot be used in the browser."

Comment: fileExistSync is not a valid function... need to use : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js

Comment: Just updated to use Node's "fs" instead of external dependency for writing and reading files.

Answer (score 134):

There is an option to save user data using the `userDataDir` option when launching puppeteer. This stores the session and other things related to launching chrome.

```
puppeteer.launch({
  userDataDir: "./user_data"
});
```

It doesn't go into great detail but here's a link to the docs for it: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.6.1&show=api-puppeteerlaunchoptions

Comment: This is a better solution, keep cookie and local storage

Comment: This is the easiest way to persist the session, though you might end up storing more data than what you need. Just launching a browser with this configuration creates a folder containing ~3mb of data.

If storage is a concern, you might want to consider @Ecovirtual solution. Otherwise, this is perfect.

Comment: Good answer
but this take more disk space, 
can I specify the cookies only to save into this folder??

Comment: I use it not't ok, what should i do?

Comment: Does this approach store SESSION cookies? Semantically, the session ends when you close the browser, so I could see the argument for not persisting session cookies between puppeteer page instances this way.

Comment: Here's a version-agnostic link to the Puppeteer docs for launch options, since the version update has killed the old link: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-puppeteerlaunchoptions

Comment: this is the better way to preserve a session without know details like cookies, session storage, localstorage, web db, etc.

Answer (score 20):

For a version of the above solution that actually works and doesn't rely on `jsonfile` (instead using the more standard `fs`) check this out:

Setup:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const cookiesPath = "cookies.txt";
```

Reading the cookies (put this code first):

```
// If the cookies file exists, read the cookies.
const previousSession = fs.existsSync(cookiesPath)
if (previousSession) {
  const content = fs.readFileSync(cookiesPath);
  const cookiesArr = JSON.parse(content);
  if (cookiesArr.length !== 0) {
    for (let cookie of cookiesArr) {
      await page.setCookie(cookie)
    }
    console.log('Session has been loaded in the browser')
  }
}
```

Writing the cookies:

```
// Write Cookies
const cookiesObject = await page.cookies()
fs.writeFileSync(cookiesPath, JSON.stringify(cookiesObject));
console.log('Session has been saved to ' + cookiesPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

For writing Cookies

```
async function writingCookies() {
const cookieArray = require(C.cookieFile); //C.cookieFile can be replaced by ('./filename.json')
await page.setCookie(...cookieArray);
await page.cookies(C.feedUrl); //C.url can be ('https://example.com')
}
```

For reading Cookies, for this, you've to install jsonfile in your project : npm install jsonfile

```
async function getCookies() {
const cookiesObject = await page.cookies();
jsonfile.writeFile('linkedinCookies.json', cookiesObject, { spaces: 2 },
  function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The Cookie file could not be written.', err);
    }
    console.log("Cookie file has been successfully saved in current working Directory : '" + process.cwd() + "'");
  })
}
```

Call these two functions using `await` and it will work for you.