# Set SessionStorage through Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, browser, screen-scraping, google-chrome-headless, session-storage

I am using puppeteer to take a screen grab. To load the required page however, a context needs to be set in the SessionStorage (of the browser page). I am not able to do achieve that as of now. Any help would be appreciated!.

`browser.newPage().then(Page => 
{ //maybe set some context here so that the page can access the context from sessionStorage
  page.goto(url).then( .....)})`

Comment: Checkout this related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608971/how-to-manage-log-in-session-through-headless-chrome

Comment: @GabrielWamunyu sessionStorage and cookies are entirely separate

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't something like this work?

```js
        await page.goto(url);
        await page.evaluate(() => {
            sessionStorage.setItem(...);
        });
```

Comment: Hm... we since took a different approach altogether, so I don't really know if it would work. However, I need the data from the sessionStorage at page load, (to authorize the user and not send him to the login screen for example). So, once we have done a page.goto(PageUrl), even if it gets set, we wont have much use for it then.

Comment: @AnweshCR7 then how did u pass the data?

Comment: @Jazzy sessionStorage doesn't exist in node ...