# How to check whether a directory exists in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'd like to save files received from json object in a REST API app and here is the code:

```
 router.post('/addphoto',  checkAuth, (req, res)=> {
  let filename = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
   let dir = './uploads/' + req.user.id;

//Not sure about this
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}

base64String = req.body.file;
let base64Image = base64String.split(';base64,').pop();
let filePath = dir + "/" + filename

fs.writeFile( filePath, base64Image, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err) {
console.log('File created');
});
...
```

It does the job but I've read that `existsSync` is deprecated, and also I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use sync code inside a router which is async by nature.

So I'm wondering what is the idiomatic way to do so in such circumstances?

Answer (score 9):

You can use access

```
fs.access(myDir, function(err) {
  if (err && err.code === 'ENOENT') {
    fs.mkdir(myDir); //Create dir in case not found
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not the right solution - if `myDir` just so happens to point to a file, this will silently fail.

Comment: I think this is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749571/5420070

Answer (score 6):

> I've read that existsSync is deprecated

It isn't. See [the manual](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path):

> fs.exists() is deprecated, **but fs.existsSync() is not**. The callback parameter to fs.exists() accepts parameters that are inconsistent with other Node.js callbacks. fs.existsSync() does not use a callback.

---

> I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use sync code inside a router which is async by nature.

There's nothing intrinsically wrong about doing something synchronous inside something that is asynchronous — **most** JS is synchronous — but it does mean that the feature would block the event loop while looking at the file system, and looking at the file system is a relatively time-consuming operation, so it wouldn't be good for performance.

Your code might not need that level of performance, but that's a judgement call we can't make for you.

[`exists`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) is right next to `existsSync` in the manual and says:

> Deprecated: Use fs.stat() or fs.access() instead.

So pick one of those.

[`access`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) has an example:

> ```
> // Check if the file exists in the current directory.
> fs.access(file, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
>   console.log(`${file} ${err ? 'does not exist' : 'exists'}`);
> });
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Can you please adjust the `fs.access` example to answer my particular case?

Comment: Access does not sound very good with promises as it would rely on errors for a legitimate check

Answer (score 4):

You can use `existsSync` as it's not deprecated. it's `exists` that got deprecated. I've attached a screenshot and link below so you can use it without any problem.

link->

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path

image->

[image]

Comment: I see. But is it a good idea to use `existsSync` inside the router (which I suppose is async) ?

Comment: Yes that's not a problem at all as it doesn't require promise to execute.

Comment: Why would it need a promise to execute? It doesn't need a promise because it is synchronous, blocking code. If it needed a promise then it wouldn't be a problem, but not using one indicates that it could be.

Comment: @Quentin that's what i said.

Comment: @AtishayJain — No, you said "that's not a problem at all" which is the opposite of what I said.

Comment: What i meant was using existsSync is not a problem at all as it does not require promise. @Quentin . Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @AtishayJain — Still the opposite of what I said, which is that as it does not require a promise it could be a problem.

Comment: @Quentin but it's already synchronous, so why do require need a promise for it?

Comment: @AtishayJain — You continue to miss the point. Because it is synchronous it is blocking. That is the problem. If it used a promise it would be because it wasn't synchronous and thus not blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Modern async/await way

```js
const isDirExist = async path => await fs.promises.access(path).then(()=>true).catch(()=>false);
```

Using

```js
const isDirExist = async path => await fs.promises.access(path).then(()=>true).catch(()=>false);

(async () => {
        
     console.log(await isDirExist('/my/path/'));

})()
```

Answer (score 1):

From official docs https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesaccesspath-mode

[image]

**fs.access** will throw an error if file don't exist. So you will not have a boolean to check if file exist or not, like [java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#exists()) does from ancient ages. You should use a try/catch:

```
var isDirExist = false;
try{
    await fs.promises.access("/foo/bar");
    isDirExist = true;
}catch(e){
    isDirExist = false;
}
```

If this looks problematic, official docs says:

> Using fsPromises.access() to check for the accessibility of a file before calling fsPromises.open() **is not recommended**. Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change the file's state between the two calls. **Instead**, user code should **open/read/write** the file **directly and handle the error** raised if the file is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [node-fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) you can utilize...

`fs.ensureDir(dir[,options][,callback])`

Which by definition...

> Ensures that the directory exists. If the directory structure does not exist, it is created.

See also [fs.ensureDirSync](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/ensureDir-sync.md)

Answer (score 0):

The below code will check if the destination exists. If it doesn't exist, it'll create the destination as a directory. It will also create the parent directories if they don't exist (because of `recursive: true`). It does not use Sync functions and will not block requests if used in a web server.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const targetDirectory = 'your/path/here';

fs.mkdir(targetDirectory, { recursive: true }, (error) => {
  if (!error) {
    console.log('Directory successfully created, or it already exists.');
    return;
  }
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EEXIST':
      // Error:
      // Requested location already exists, but it's not a directory.
      break;
    case 'ENOTDIR':
      // Error:
      // The parent hierarchy contains a file with the same name as the dir
      // you're trying to create.
      break;
    default:
      // Some other error like permission denied.
      console.error(error);
      break;
  }
});
```

See: [mkdir docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_options_callback).