# fs.existsSync is not a function in Nuxt JS + Lowdb

Tags: node.js, json, nuxt.js, lowdb

**What I need:**

Read a local JSON file inside NuxtJS as the page loads. So I can parse it into a prop within `<option>` tag.

**What I have:**

Lowdb (installed as dependency — to read the JSON file) inside a component, with this code:

```
computed: {
        resultFetchCamera: function() {
            const low = require('lowdb')
            const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')
            const adapter = new FileSync('db.json');
            const db = low(adapter);
            let value = db.get('Size').map('Name').value();
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

I got an error `This dependency was not found: * fs in ./node_modules/lowdb/adapters/FileSync.js`. Fixed with [this solution](https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module/issues/11#issuecomment-376780588). Which leads me to another error: `TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function`. [This solution](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300#issuecomment-248773783) helps out a bit but it also leads to other errors: `TypeError: window.require is not a function` and `TypeError: FileSync is not a constructor`. So, I undo the last solution and get back with the fs.existsSync error.

**The question:**

1. How to fix the fs.existsSync error (in a NuxtJS environment)?
2. Did I implement Lowdb to NuxtJS correctly?

Comment: What version of Node.js is being used? `existsSync` has had a [varied existence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482701/157247), but should be present in modern vesions of Node.js.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm using v12.16.2.